# Tab Bar controller won't respond to viewControllers in the "more" section

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a tab bar view controller that is controlling just about everything in my app. I have manually coded it within my appDelegate and it displays all the views just fine but does not respond to certain things when it comes to all the view controllers that are in the "more" tab section (this is automatically created if you 6 or more view controllers). I cannot even add icons to be displayed beside the view controller name... They only show up in the main tab bar section and not in the table list.

Does anyone know why this is happening only in this part of my app? Here are examples of code that work in OTHER view controllers but NOT in the "more" section:

```
 nav7.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:117/255 green:4/255 blue:32/255 alpha:1]; //(in appDelegate.m)


       UIImage *tab6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"130-dice.png"];
NSArray *tabBarImages = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4, tab5,tab6, nil]autorelease]; 
NSInteger tabBarItemCounter; 
for (tabBarItemCounter = 0; tabBarItemCounter < [tabBarItems count]; tabBarItemCounter++) 
{ 
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [tabBarItems objectAtIndex:tabBarItemCounter]; 
    tabBarItem.image = [tabBarImages objectAtIndex:tabBarItemCounter]; 
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you properly set a `title` and `image` on the tab bar item of a view controller it should work just fine, like so:

```
- (id)init {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    self.tabBarItem.title = @"Videos";
    self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"video"];
  }
  return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Erik. However; this did not work? I am not sure if I explained it well but what I mean is if you go into the youtube app for iphone, it has a "more" section within the tab bar. From here you can see History, Most Recent etc etc. I have the same thing showing up in my app but I can't get the little images beside "history" and those others. Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: There are no other suggestions. Either the error must be somewhere else in your code, the image data is corrupted or you referenced the images incorrectly (e.g. `imageNamed:` returns nil).